# How to include annotations in generated kdoc

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-dokka, kdoc

I have a spring boot project with methods that have annotations on them, e.g.:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('organization', '$USERS_MANAGE' )")
fun listUsers(userContext: UserContext): List<User> {
    return userDAO.list(userContext.organizationId).map { it.toUser() }
}
```

When I use dokka to generate the kdoc the `PreAuthorize` annotation is not included. Here is the generated kdoc:

```
list     fun listUsers(userContext: UserContext): List<User>
```

Is there a way to include the annotation in the generated doc?

Comment: It also has a different return type. Are you sure it's the same method?

Comment: Sorry, copy paste error. Edited it now.

Comment: Is the `PreAuthorize` annotation itself annotated as `@Documented?` If you generate Javadoc for a _Java_ function with the same signature and annotations, does `PreAuthorize` show up in the generated Javadoc?

Comment: Yes, `PreAuthorize` has the `@Documented` annotation. And the generated Javadoc includes the `PreAuthorize` and other annotations. Do you know if it is possible to "convert" generated javadoc to kdoc?